# Google Maps or Places: API to fetch bulk uploaded (and verified) locations

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

We have bulk uploaded our client's locations, and they are in the process of being verified by Google. Once that is done, we would like to use the data in our client's iOS and Android apps, as part of a Store Locator feature.

i.e. we want to lookup the exact verified business locations and associated details, by an id, as opposed to text search, which could potentially hit some other businesses, or previous listings of our client's locations (which are not the official and verified versions).

I have tried to look at both the Google Places API as well as Google Maps API, but I cannot find any mention of a group id or anything of this sort. I might be looking completely in the wrong direction, so thought it would be worth while trying SO.

So, to rephrase the question, is there an API endpoint to fetch a bulk uploaded list of locations (some 150 of them), to consume in an iOS and an Android native application. No code examples needed, just looking for a pointer to the correct Google product / API for this, if one exists.

PS> I am not familiar with Google Maps API for Work. We were hoping for a free route, but if that sorts out the use case, it's also acceptable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the Places API has the concept of a group ID that represents multiple place IDs.  I think you will have to simply collect the individual [Place IDs](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id) of your uploaded locations.